# the wrong side of midnight

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It's true he didn't sleep much last night. It had come to him, **the
>   wrong side of midnight**, that More was no doubt asleep himself, not
>   knowing that it was his last night on earth. It is not usual, till the
>   morning, to prepare the condemned man; so, he had thought, any vigil I
>   keep for him, I keep alone.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

What does **the bold phrase** mean?

Comment: A learner might find the syntax confusing. It is a temporal phrase identifying when the idea  came to him, that is, after midnight, as StoneyB says.  A temporal phrase does not require a preposition. Compare:  "... and *(on) the day* of the big race, he awoke early."  **On** is optional there. Or "Where were you, Mr Jones, *the morning* of the 25th of May? asked the detective."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The wrong side of midnight* is a mildly jocular phrase for the very early hours of the morning, after midnight. It's the "wrong" side because it's a time when nobody should be doing anything but sleeping.